# Digital Clock C Code Won't Show the Correct Time

Tags: c, loops, cygwin, clock

In my college programming class, I’m coding this digital clock in C. I can’t figure out why the correct time isn’t showing up. The minutes and seconds both stay stuck on the number 60.

Here’s the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int h=0,m=0,s=0;
    printf("enter time in format of hh mm ss");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &h,&m,&s);
    start:;
    for (h;h<12;h++) {
        for (m;m<60;m++) {
            for (s;s<60;s++) {
                printf("%d:%d:%d",h,m,s);
                for (double i=0;i<99999999; i++) {
                    i++;
                    i--;
                }
            }
            s=0;
        }
        m=0;
    }  
goto start;
}
```

Comment: `for(double i=0;i<99999999; i++){
                    i++;
                    i--;                       }` what is this?

Comment: Don't use labels and `goto` for loops.

Comment: Well that's because there's nothing that makes them not 60 once they are 60, silly!

Comment: As for your problem, now it's the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Use `for (int m = 0; m < 60; m++)` if you can (and remove the earlier definition of `m` and later assignment to `m`); use `for (m = 0; m < 60; m++)` if you can't (and still remove the assignment, but you'll need the definition).  Initialize loop control variables in the loop control if you can; it is seldom that you can't do that.  Ditto for hours and seconds too.

Comment: @Mitchel0022, I suspect it's supposed to be the same as `sleep(1)` in the absence of something that will sleep for a second.

Answer (score 2):

well, there are a few issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
    int h=0,m=0,s=0;
    printf("enter time in format of hh mm ss");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &h,&m,&s);
start:
      for (;h<12;h++) {
          for (;m<60;m++) {
              for (;s<60;s++) {
                  printf("%d:%d:%d\n",h,m,s);
                  /*
                  for (double i=0;i<99999999; i++) {
                      i++;
                      i--;
                      */
                  sleep(1);

              }
              s=0;
          }
          m=0;
      }  
      goto start;
}
```

1. try and avoid `goto` if possible - there are only a few places this construct should be used... this is not one of them
2. the `for` loop makes no sense - since it increases and decreases the same value - it will be stuck in an infinte loop
3. the `scanf` statment `%d%d%d` without specifiyng the number of digits will not work, either go with my code example or try `%2d%2d%2d`
4. you are not validating your input
5. in the for loops what is the purpose of the variable in the first section
6. sleep - will produce somthing which will look nice but it is not accurate - I suggest reading more about time functions...

IMPORTENT NOTE: this example is bad coding but I hope it can give you a starting point.. as is, this is simply put... bad

Comment: The for loop wont be infinite, the `i++ and i--` cancel out but the `i++` in the for loop definition will eventually terminate. Though I agree the for loop makes no sense. The infinite loop comes from the jump to start at the end of the program